# xml cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: xml, eclipse, field, preferences

We created the xml file preferences in res/xml and Eclipse reports an error: "xml cannot be resolved or is not a field".

```
package org.example.asteroides;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity{

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error. Then I changed this file's location to: `/xml/preferences.xml`
once you have placed the file in proper location, refresh the project in eclipse and the error will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

You missed one of the imports

```
import com.yourpackagename.R;
```